# How to use StompJS for a WebSocket connection in a typescript react project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, websocket

I am working on a notification system with push notifications for a project and can't seem to properly set up a minimal WebSocket connection just to test that everything is working, P.S (I am new to WebSockets).

For the Api I am using spring boot, here is what I have now:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      const sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/ws');
      stompClient = over(sock);
      stompClient.connect({}, onError);
      stompClient.subscribe('/all/public', onPublicMessageReceived);
      stompClient.subscribe(`/user/${user.id}/private`, onPrivateMessageReceived);
    }
  }, []);

  const onPublicMessageReceived = (payload: any) => {
    const payloadData = JSON.parse(payload.body);
    console.log(payloadData);
  };

  const onError = (error: any) => {
    console.log(error);
  };

  const onPrivateMessageReceived = (payload: any) => {
    const payloadData = JSON.parse(payload);
    console.log(payloadData);
  };

  const handleSendPublicMessage = () => {
    if (stompClient) {
      const randomData: any = {
        data: 'random',
      };
      stompClient.send('/app/message', {}, JSON.stringify(randomData));
    }
  };
```

And here are my imports:

```
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import { over } from '@stomp/stompjs';
```

Here it gives me this error:

> Module '"@stomp/stompjs"' has no exported member 'over'.ts(2305)

Then if I try to change the import declaration to this:

```
import { over } from 'stompjs';
```

It doesn't immediately show any errors and it even seems like typescript recognized it, but when the app compiles it shows this error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stompjs' in 'C:\CODE\PROJECTS\VSCODE\kau-2023-spring-tautvydas-fe\src\components\header\Notifications'
>
> ERROR in ./src/components/header/Notifications/NotificationsDropdown.tsx 12:0-31
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stompjs' in 'C:\CODE\PROJECTS\VSCODE\kau-2023-spring-tautvydas-fe\src\components\header\Notifications'

Here are the dependencies I have installed:

- npm install u/stomp/stompjs ws
- npm install @stomp/stompjs
- npm install --save @types/stompjs
- npm i net
- npm i sockjs-client
- npm i --save-dev @types/sockjs-client

Most of the tutorials I've found use react with vanilla JS and most of the problems I am facing seem to do with typescript itself
Does anyone have any ideas how to fix these issues and set up a WebSocket connection using react with typescript? I would greatly appreciate any help :)

Answer (score -1):

use `Stomp.over()` instead of `over()` because it is a static method accessed by the class itself.